# Segmentation fault when returning string from function in c++

Tags: c++

I have an error in my class. 
I'm suspect it's something simple, maybe me failing to understand how strings works in C++.
My function tries to returns local std::string to another std::string, but instead of getting the string, I'm getting segmentation fault after the function returns.
This is my code:

```
    TestClass::TestClass(std::string a, std::string b)
    {
        m_a = a;
        m_b = b;
    }

    std::string TestClass::stringHandler()
    {
        const char myTemplate[] = "a=%s,b=%s";
        char formattedString[strlen(myTemplate) + m_a.length() + m_b.length()];
        sprintf( formattedString, myTemplate, m_a.c_str(), m_b.c_str());
        std::cout << "formattedString= " << formattedString << "\n";
        std::string returnStr(formattedString);
        std::cout << "returnStr=" << returnStr << "\n";
        return returnStr;
    }

    int main(...)
    {
        /* getting a and b from argv */
        TestClass MyClassObj(a, b);
        std::string strRet = MyClassObj.stringHandler();
        std::cout << "Back after stringHandler\n";
        return 0
    }
```

In stringHandler, when I'm printing returnStr, it displayes properly.
But right after that, I'm getting Segmentation fault, and "Back after stringHandler" is not being printed.
Do any of you masters, have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Always use snprintf, never sprintf, to avoid buffer overruns.

Comment: Interesting choices for format strings in there... Why do I harbor doubts `%b` and `%c` are in your *real* code ? Assuming they're actually `%s`, what makes you think the `a=`, `b=`, etc., as well as the terminator, apparently take **no** space ?  You're overwriting your string buffer and invoking undefined behavior. Finally, you have three format specifiers, yet only two actual arguments. Stop messing with `sprintf` and use a `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: Oops :), I fixed it to %s (as it is on my real code). a and b are a one word string (I verify that before going to stringHandler)

Comment: Your latest code works for me without any error.

Comment: I'd suggest using an `std::stringstream` instead of `sprintf` and avoiding buffer overrun problems altogether if you're going to do a lot of operations.

Comment: Still looking for a good reason to use `std::stringstream` instead of `std::string + operator`.

Comment: I want to parse a and b into my template. In reality its a long string that contains a lot of text other that a & b. std::ostringstream does not support formatting string such as sprintf (or snprintf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues:

- `%b` is not a valid format specifier.
- You have 3 format specifiers (if `%b` is fixed!) but you only passed 2 arguments.
- You didn't allocate enough memory for `formattedString`.
- Arrays with runtime size are illegal in C++

**(update:)** after the edits to OP, the first three of these were fixed, so if your compiler also has an extension for runtime array size then this code would not cause a segfault.

The simplest fix is just to write:

```
std::string returnStr = "a=" + m_a + ",b=" + m_b;
```

But supposing you want to stick with `printf` formatting, here is one way to do it.
Although it is possible to calculate and work out the exact amount of space, that is fragile. It'd be easy to cause a buffer overflow if you made a change to `myTemplate`.

One plan would be to allocate a large amount of space. A more robust way is to use `snprintf` to determine the buffer size first:

```
char const myTemplate[] = "a=%s,b=%s";
size_t expect_len = std::snprintf(NULL, 0, myTemplate, m_a.c_str(), m_b.c_str());

if ( expect_len == -1 )
    throw std::runtime_error("snprintf failed");

std::vector<char> buffer(expect_len + 1);
std::snprintf(&buffer[0], buffer.size(), myTemplate, m_a.c_str(), m_b.c_str());

std::string returnStr(buffer);
```

In C++11 you could actually `snprintf` directly into `returnStr`.

To be clear, the whole `printf` idea is not very safe as you can cause undefined behaviour if `myTemplate` contains something you didn't expect. (I presume you did it this way to allow yourself to specify a different format string at runtime).  So use it with caution.

Comment: Thank you so much! Its working now. myTemplate is a predefined char const, but a very long one (it is a soap request actually, and I'm parsing the params into it before sending)